# Easiest way to implement .Contains() on a ICollection<Tuple<T1,T2>>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, collections

Suppose I have a `Dictionary<String, Tuple<T1,T2>>` and I want to determine if the any of the dictionary values has V1 for its T1.  How would I do this most elegantly?

Linq?

Comment: That's my .net 3.5 version of the Tuple class.  It's just the value of T1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, this comes to mind:

```
var exists = dict.Values.Any(t => t.Item1 == v1);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
bool b = dictionary.Any(item => item.Value.Item1 == searchTerm);
```